# VS Code Tabs will not line up letters

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to make a grid area in CSS, and I realized my tabs will not line up so I can make it a nice square. I tried everything I can think of to get them to line up. I tried

- Tab width
- Font size
- Letter spacing
- Font weight
- editor.renderWhitespace
- Different fonts such as Arial, Ubuntu Regulat, Adobe Fan Heiti Std,
- editor.fontLigatures

I am not sure how I can fix this? Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about
[image: Pic here]

Notice how the letters don't line up at all, they're all tabs, not spaces. I tried this in sublime text 3 and it lines up, how can I get this to line up in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [monospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font like `Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace`.

To reset to the defaults, click the gear next to the **Editor: Font Family** setting.

[image: Editor:Font Family setting with default fonts selected]

Answer (score 0):

The given answer is incorrect. I'm using OCR or Proggy, both monospace fonts, and never had a problem until a recent update - now my tabs no longer line up. This is an issue with an update or change in the settings that MS caused.